# .Net BackgroundWorker not responding

Tags: c#, winforms, thread-safety

I am creating a `BackgroundWorker` in my C# application. Inside `DoWork`, few web services is called. Everything is working fine but as soon as the `DoWork` process is completed, the application is non-responsive. And also, I am not updating any UI component from `BackgroundWorker`.

Here is the code being executed in `DoWork`

```
 private void bwNQUpdate_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
     int nStatusCode = 0;

     QDetails[] pQDetails = null;
     string queueName = "test_queue";

     int nQLength = cMezeoFileCloud.NQGetLength(ServiceUrl, queueName, ref nStatusCode);
     if (nQLength > 0)
         pQDetails = cFileCloud.GetData(ServiceUrl, queueName, nQLength, ref nStatusCode);

     if (pQDetails != null)
     {        
         for (int n = 0; n < pQDetails[0].nTotalQ; n++)
         {             
             UpdateFromNQ(pNQDetails[n]);
             cFileCloud.QValue(ServiceUrl , queueName, 1, ref nStatusCode);
         } 
     }     
 }
```

And on `RunWorkerCompleted`

```
private void bwNQUpdate_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
      MessageBox.Show("Download completed.");
}
```

After execution of `RunWorkerCompleted`, application is not responding.

Comment: Post your code! It is hard to get a feel for what could be going wrong without it!

Comment: WPF or Form application?

Comment: What code is executing on the main thread when this happens?

Comment: @ebattulga: It is a Form application.

Comment: @svick: Just displaying a progress bar with marquee.

Comment: No, I mean what code is at the top of the stack of the main thread when this happens. You can find that out in a debugger.

Comment: Are you certian that you are not trying to access the UI thread from the `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: @Killercam: yes, I am accessing UI thread from background worker.

Comment: Just to confirm, you cannot update the visual display (governed by the UI thread) from a `BackgroundWorker`. Calling for instance `MessageBox.Show()` from a `BackgroundWorker` will throw an exception. Sorry if you already know this...

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles upon this last remark: the RunWorkerCompleted event actually runs on the thread where the backgroundworker was created. So a MessageBox.Show() there is not a problem: it runs on the UI thread.

Comment: @VinodMaurya: Just check that if you comment all your code in `DoWork` handler, does it still hangs ?

Answer (score 1):

First, check to see if `MessageBox.Show("Download completed.");` gets called by using a break point.

If it does get called, try invoking the message box call instead of calling it directly. Basically, any events fired from within the background worker may be coming from its under lying thread.

Answer (score 0):

RunWorkerCompleted you have written is perfectly fine. 
RunWorkerCompleted event is handled by the invoking thread, not the worker thread. 
Even if you do MessageBox.Show from background thread there will not be a problem as the thread will make its own Uicomponent.

The problem i doubt is within your DoWork.